# Reassured to know/hear

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Can one say

> You will be reassured to know/hear.

?

Take *e.g.* the following sentences, made up by myself:

> The Arabic and Hebrew scripts have no vowels - however, the learner will be reassured to know that the vowel-sounds are generally indicated by other means.

Or:

> You will be reassured to hear that Charles has abandoned his intention to go skydiving.

My simple question is: Is this good/proper English? What might be a more suitable reformulation of the above sentences?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I would say "you will be *relieved* to hear that Charles has abandoned his intention to go skydiving". It would be fine to say *know* instead of *hear*.

Comment: You will be reassured to learn that you can take your pick.

Comment: I'd choose 'to know' in the _vowels_ example, as it encourages the learner (knowledge being power, or at least what we're expected to know to pass the exams). And (as nnnnnn suggests) I'd choose '[relieved] to hear' in the _skydiving_ example, as it emphasises the 'bearer of good tidings' aspect.